# Nativescript tab items fail to trigger tap functions

Tags: nativescript

I am trying to create a two-part scrollable tab navigation bar and content window. The tabs I have made so far do not trigger the associated function when tapped.

navbar.component.tns.html

```
<ScrollView orientation="horizontal" height="10%">
    <TabView>
        <StackLayout *tabItem="{title: 'Home'}" (tap)="tapHome()">
        </StackLayout>
        <StackLayout *tabItem="{title: 'Players'}" (tap)="tapPlayers()">
        </StackLayout>
        <StackLayout *tabItem="{title: 'Teams'}" (tap)="tapTeams()">
        </StackLayout>
        <StackLayout *tabItem="{title: 'Organizers'}" (tap)="tapOrganizers()">
        </StackLayout>
        <StackLayout *tabItem="{title: 'Tournaments'}" (tap)="tapTournaments()">
        </StackLayout>
    </TabView>
</ScrollView>
```

navbar.component.ts

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { TabView, TabViewItem, SelectedIndexChangedEventData } from "tns-core-modules/ui/tab-view";
import { PrimaryWindowComponent } from '../primary-window/primary-window.component';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-navbar',
  templateUrl: './navbar.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./navbar.component.css']
})
export class NavbarComponent implements OnInit {

  constructor(public window: PrimaryWindowComponent) { }

  ngOnInit() {
    console.log("navbar start!");
  }

  public tapHome(){
    console.log("tapHome pressed!");
  }
}

//export function 

export function tapPlayers(){

}

export function tapTeams(){

}

export function tapOrganizers(){

}

export function tapTournaments(args: GestureEventData){
  console.log("tapTournaments pressed!");
}
```

I have tried tap="function", (tap)="function", tap="function()", (tap)="function()", (tap)="{{function()}}", and tap="{{function()}}". The first four don't work, the second to last triggers an error, and the last one causes the intended ontap function to trigger once after initialization then cease functioning from there on out.

Comment: Please share a Playground sample where the issue can be reproduced.

Comment: https://play.nativescript.org/?template=play-ng&id=3Yuq6V

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are not suppose to wrap the `TabView` inside `ScrollView`, it doesn't require or add any value.

```
 <TabView>
    <StackLayout *tabItem="{title: 'Home'}" (tap)="tapHome()">
    </StackLayout>
    <StackLayout *tabItem="{title: 'Players'}" (tap)="tapPlayers()">
    </StackLayout>
    <StackLayout *tabItem="{title: 'Teams'}" (tap)="tapTeams()">
    </StackLayout>
    <StackLayout *tabItem="{title: 'Organizers'}" (tap)="tapOrganizers()">
    </StackLayout>
    <StackLayout *tabItem="{title: 'Tournaments'}" (tap)="tapTournaments()">
    </StackLayout>
</TabView>
```

With above snippet, it should allow tap events.